# Objective vs subjective case

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement, objective-case

1. They came for her and me
2. They came for her and i

Which one is correct according to grammar?

Comment: This is more suited to English Learners SE. Anyhow, the answer is 1. _for_ there is a preposition and demands an object. Also, every sentence must be ended with a period.

Comment: As I always tell people who ask this kind of question, _try the sentence with the other person left out_. You wouldn't say 'They came for I", would you?

Comment: _I_ is only used for a subject. It doesn't matter whether there's an _and_ or not. If it's not the subject, don't use _I_ (or _he, she, we,_ or _they_, the other nominative pronouns).